# Possible to convert ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<CustomModel>?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm saving some ArrayList in Sharedpreferences. But I want to set my custom model to ArrayList in adapter cause get items with getter. I really tired too many solutions from stackoverflow but I couldn't do that.

```
private ArrayList<String> fullList = new ArrayList<>();
```

to

```
private ArrayList<MyCustom> fullList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**My Custom Class:**

```
public class InstagramUserSummary implements Serializable {
public boolean is_verified;
public String profile_pic_id;
public boolean is_favorite;
public boolean is_private;
public String username;
public long pk;
public String profile_pic_url;
public boolean has_anonymous_profile_picture;
public String full_name;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(username, pk);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if (obj == this) return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof InstagramUserSummary)) {
        return false;
    }

    InstagramUserSummary user = (InstagramUserSummary) obj;
    return pk == user.getPk();

}}
```

**List coming like this:**

```
[InstagramUserSummary(super=dev.niekirk.com.instagram4android.requests.payload.InstagramUserSummary@a4acf205, is_verified=false, profile_pic_id=1773528799482591987_1654599017, is_favorite=false, is_private=false, username=ququletta, pk=1654599017, profile_pic_url=https://instagram.fada1-5.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/8d99014623ed527e52512a20002d884b/5C387E45/t51.2885-19/s150x150/31203725_200759604054857_5778864946146181120_n.jpg, has_anonymous_profile_picture=false, full_name=Ququletta)]
```

Thanks.

Comment: share your `MyCustom` class with question

Comment: what is MyCustom?

Comment: Please share MyCustom model class code.

Comment: Hi. I shared sorry for that.

Comment: So you want to get a list of the usernames?

Comment: Yes but I can not.

Comment: As a side note: in your case I'd use `ListAdapter`.

Comment: There will be lot of modifications in your adapter class

Comment: Please paste your Activity/Fragment class from where the adapter is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Suppose you have a String variable in MyCustom class, like:

```
public class MyCustom {

    private String strName;

    public MyCustom(String name) {
        this.strName = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.strName = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
         return this.strName;
    }
}
```

then, you can do something like this:

```
for (MyCustom value : fullList) {
    customFullList.add(new MyCustom(value))
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you check my custom class again please

Comment: @Nina Your custom class has many different data type's variables, but your question says to convert only String ArrayList to Custom arraylist, that can only be done if even you have only string variable in your custom class. I hope you get my point here.

Comment: @Nina Please upvote it too as it may help others.. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need to have the `username` field be a public member of the `MyCustom` class. Since you're exposing access to the field via getters/setters having it public is wrong.

Aside from that, you can easily use streams and a mapping function to create a new `MyCustom` instance from a Stream of String.

In order to avoid boilerplate code, I would go ahead and create a static creator method in `MyCustom` like this:

```
public class MyCustom {

    private String userName;
    public String getUserName() { return userName; }
    public void setUserName(String userName) { this.userName = userName; }

    public static MyCustom from(final String userName) {
        MyCustom custom = new MyCustom();
        custom.setUserName(userName);
        return custom;
    }

}
```

And then I would use this as a method reference to convert Strings over to MyCustoms thus collecting them into a new list like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<MyCustom> customs = list.stream()
        .map(MyCustom::from)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Finally, also avoid initializing lists using the concrete type (e.g. `ArrayList<String> someList = new ArrayList<>;'`. It's much better to code the interfaces, thus doing something like `List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>`.